# Slash included words from string

Tags: regex, slash

I have a string as follows and I want to have only highlighted text in RegEx:

"Datapath from **SF7PCRINFVCR1/MPLS to SF2PCRINFVCR1/MPLS** for fwdClass fc_nc is down".

I have tried the RegEx `(?<=Datapath from ).*?(?= for)` but I am expecting the result as second row under Group Details [attached screenshot] with
Match#2 GroupIndex#1 and GroupContent as  SF7PCRINFVCR1/MPLS to SF2PCRINFVCR1/MPLS from the below site as my integration tool is looking for second entry form the Group Details section.

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#before-output

[image: Regex_OP_screenshot]

Expecting output like [image: Expecting Output]

Comment: You can simply wrap the middle part in a group `(.*?)`. The result will be in group 0 *and* in 1 but that would be compatible. Group 0 is always the whole string found. The slash has nothing to do with it (since that's in your question title thought I would mention).

Comment: Thanks Peter. 
Can you help me with regex in getting Group 0 as whole string and Group 1 only with (.*?)

Comment: Well you could just remove the lookbehind and lookahead.. does this work for you? `Datapath from (.*?) for.*`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the prompt support. It helped me out to get the expected outcome. Appreciate all the community members for all your Faster and Better Answers.